# Continue loop in reading excel rows even when an exception occurred in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, loops, exception, plsql

Here's the overview of the code:

```
PROCEDURE

BEGIN
  WHILE LOOP --loop each row
    --Read each row and add in table
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
    --log error
    ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Ex: There are 5 lines. The 3rd line has an error in it. The program stops right after it reads the error line, making the other lines next to it not evaluated/read. My goal is after it went to the exception, it will output the line and continue with reading the other lines. So how do I return back to the loop if it went to the exception?

Comment: Put those lines of yours in a separate `begin end` block with its own exception handler(`begin exception end`). You did not explain how exactly you read those Excel rows, but usually `insert into .. select ` statement with `log errors`(10gR2 and up) clause is enough, unless you perform some complex transformation that cannot be done in pure SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, then you will cache error only in inner anonymous block:

```
PROCEDURE

BEGIN
  WHILE LOOP --loop each row
    BEGIN
      --Read each row and add in table
      COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
        --log error
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
  END LOOP;

END;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using a independent PL/SQL block in the loop itself.

```
BEGIN
      WHILE LOOP --loop each row
        BEGIN
        --Read each row and add in table
        COMMIT;
            EXCEPTION --Catch the exception here and print the data and it will move on
        END;
      END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
        --log error
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
```

Comment: Without any text, answers like this appears in the Low Quality Review Queue. This means that there's a risk your answer is deleted. I don't know anything about this topic so I can't really tell if it is low quality or not, but I suggest you add a small paragraph stating what is different from your code and the OP's post. Preferably with an explanation of why this works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out and Stack overflow asks me that too. But it was very self explanatory for the relevant audience. Anyways, considering the quality of people here, i am not sure if missing answer deserves a downvote without looking at the quality of answer. But without further ado, i will edit this.